# C++ - Error when compiling

Tags: c++, class, header, account, bank

This is my header file which consists of a class and it's functions. I believe I've not declared the functions correctly so could someone please point out where my errors are? Thanks a lot! There's gotta be some rookie mistake here, I'm kinda new to C++.

```
using namespace std;



class bankAccount
{
    public:
        int accNo;
        int password;

        double balance;
        double withdrawamt;
        double depositamt;

        char name[20];
        char address[40];
        char username[10];

    public:

        double checkbalance();
        double deposit();
        double withdraw();

};

bankAccount::withdraw()
{
       cout << "Enter Withdraw amount: ";
       cin >> withdrawamt;
       if (balance > withdrawamt)
          balance = (balance - withdrawamt);     
}
```

Comment: It would certainly help a lot if you could include the errors you are actually encountering !

Comment: `name[20]` looks like a design that can't possibly go wrong and come back to bite you once it's rolled out to customers.

Comment: Why don't you try compiling a minimal class first, and take it from there? There is just too much that is wrong in your example.

Comment: This code shows a true lack of C/C++ knowledge. (E.g. no return type for the function definition, no return statement in a function that needs one...). You should look for C++ learning materials.

Answer (score 2):

You have no return type in your withdraw function. It should be: `double bankAccount::withdraw()`

Instead of `bankAccount::withdraw()`

Check the function prototypes in your header and the error codes of your compiler. For instance, copy-pasting to [ideone](http://www.ideone.com) gives the answer straight away:

> prog.cpp:25:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘withdraw’ with no type [-fpermissive]
>   prog.cpp:25:1: error: prototype for ‘int bankAccount::withdraw()’ does not match any in class ‘bankAccount’
>   prog.cpp:
>   21:16: error: candidate is: double bankAccount::withdraw()

Good luck

Edit:

1. I forgot to make explicit that you should also add a return statement in your withdraw method.
2. You should ask yourself if you really want to use static arrays for name, address, and username. And my two cents would be to make a seperate class for the user, because an address does not logically belong to a bankaccount (not to me anyway).
3. Deposit should take as an argument a double, and return void.
4. You don't need to have a member variable for the withdraw amount and the the deposit amount. Make them local variables, or even better pass them as arguments to your methods as in the code below.

Here is an alternative implementation, note that I left in the names and passwords, but really these should be moved to different classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class bankAccount
{
    public:
    int accNo;
    int password;

    vector<string> name;
    vector<string> address;
    vector<string> username;

    private:
    double balance;

    public:
    bankAccount(double deposit) : balance(deposit) {}
    double checkBalance() { return balance; }
    void deposit(double amount);
    void withdraw(double amount);

};

void bankAccount::deposit(double amount)
{
    balance += amount;
}

void bankAccount::withdraw(double amount)
{
    if (balance > amount)
        balance = (balance - amount);  
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bankAccount someOnesAccount = bankAccount(20.0);
    someOnesAccount.deposit(30);
    someOnesAccount.withdraw(15);
    cout << someOnesAccount.checkBalance();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this is a little more helpfull. I appologize for the bad answer before. Also, note that there is a lot still to improve on this code.

Answer (score 1):

If this is all in a header file, avoid using `using namespace std;`
You can put the function implementation into a source file, and then when you use cout and cin , which need the standard namespace, you won't need the using in the header.

Answer (score 0):

considerations in your program:

1. `double withdraw();` declare with return type but your function definition doesn't return any double value.
2. Your function definition doesn't define with return type double `bankAccount::withdraw()` as your declaration.
3. So if your function not suppose to return define and declare both places use `void` as return type. if you need to return anything use same return type in define and declare and make sure to return a value.
4. Be sure initialize the member variables before use (probably inside constructor).

Additionally recommend you to fallow this tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

since ur method is returning a "**double**" value i.e **balance** in that case you must include a return type in ur syntax when you are writing the definition of the function withdraw().

Here is the corrected line of code.

```
double bankAccount::withdraw()
{
---
}
```